# How to get n from n-1

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

I know this question is probably trivial, but I'm having great difficulty with it for some reason. So, I want to solve for $p$:

$n-1 \geq 2(n-p)$

I know that the answer is $n \leq 2p -1  =\frac{n+1}{2} \leq p$ but I don't actually know how to get this.

I know for example though, that $A^{n-1} * A = A^n$

Comment: What did you try? Simply multiply 2 to $n$ and $p$ and then solve for p.

Comment: I don't understand. Why $2p-1=\frac{n-1}2$? And what do you mean with that of $A^{n-1}*A=A^n$? What has it to do with the inequality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$n-1 \geq 2(n-p) \overset{(1)}{\iff} n-1 \geq 2n -2p \overset{(2)}{\iff} 2p \geq n+1 \overset{(3)}{\iff} p \geq \frac{n+1}{2}$$
(1) develop $2(n-p)$

(2) add $2p-(n-1)$ on both sides of the inequality

(3) divide both sides of the inequality by $2$

Comment: Thanks very much, I don't know why I had so much difficulty with this! Much appreciated